# SQL Server CE connecting string not allowing for data insertion

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

OK, I've been working on this since late last night and early this morning. I am trying to insert some data into a SQL Server CE database. I am at the end of my rope.

Here is the code I am trying to implement:

```
public static void InsertData(string sqlStatement)
{
        try
        {
            //string strConn = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
            //string StartupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Remove(0, 6); // remove file:\\
            //string connectionString = @"Data Source=Database1.sdf";
            //string connectionString = @"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf";
            //string connectionString = @"Data Source = C:\Users\My\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VIN_Decoder\VIN Decoder\VIN Decoder\Database1.sdf"
            //string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0}; Persist Security Info=False;", Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.sdf"));

            //THIS ONE ACTUALLY WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!! :
            //string connectionString = @"Data Source = C:\Users\My\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VIN_Decoder\VIN Decoder\VIN Decoder\Database1.sdf"

            string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString;
            SqlCeConnection sqlceCon = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
            sqlceCon.Open();

            SqlCeCommand sqlCeCom = new SqlCeCommand(sqlStatement, sqlceCon);
            sqlCeCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCeCom.Dispose();
            sqlceCon.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

You can see all of the commented connection strings to see what I have tried. The strange thing is that I can simply use the following connection string in another method (a SELECT statement, not an INSERT INTO statement) that gets a single value from the data and it works fine.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf";
```

I have tested the query directly and like the comment says, the static path does work so that tells me my query is good. But of course I need something relative for publishing and multi-developer development.

Most of the connection strings I have tried allow the try block to complete with no errors, but the data doesn't get inserted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of .NET do you use? .NET 2.0?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 with 4.0 framework... thanks for any help in advance

Comment: The insert statement looks like this: '"INSERT INTO VIN_Cache VALUES ('FAHP0816R1', '2009', 'Ford', 'Fusion', '4 Door Sedan', 'SEL', 'V6, 3.0L', 'MEXICO', 'Hermosillo, Mexico', 'FWD', 'Dual Air Bag; Active Belts; Side Air Bag', 'Passenger Car', 'Mid-size Car', 'Gasoline', '203HP')"'

Comment: Are you sure you're inserting and checking the exact same `Database1.sdf`?

Comment: As far as being sure that I am inserting, yes. Like I said, I have tested the query (insert statement) and it also works fine with the static connection string path. As for being the same Database1.sdf file, there is only one in that directory of course. Hmmm. You do bring up a good point that it could be inserting into another copy of the database if it is pointing to the wrong one. But then again, I should be getting a redundant pk error

Comment: I stumbled upon that a few times where I inserted values in `...\Projects\Project\Release` and checked in `...\Projects\Project\Debug` or vice versa.

Comment: yes yes. I think you are right. i just did a search for the db name on my drive and found two copies. There was a second copy in the bin\debug folder. I deleted it and ran the insert statement again. db in bin\debug came back. Now the question is... WHY?

Comment: Properties of Database1.sdf => copy if newer / copy always. Both options will *copy* the Database1.sdf to the Debug/Release Folder. (which is what you usually *want* if you made changes to the DB. Just keep in mind to check the right one after you inserted data via your program ;))

Comment: Ok, I created a connection to the second copy that is in the bin\debug folder and sure enough, that is where my data is going. I checked my path in the solution explorer and it is correct (not the bin\debug copy's path) and checked the path in the Server Explorer and it also shows correct. Any ideas to what is making it point to the bin\debug folder? VS created the db and set the paths so it was nothing explicit on my part.

Comment: Thanks Corak. Let me give it a try. :)

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15460492/468244)? It looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: When you run your program, it will run "inside" the debug folder (Debug folder is Application.StartupPath). So that's why when you run it, all your relative paths will point there. Again, this is, what you usually *want*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched my heart out before posting this question, but Simon is right about similarity. However, we're going to have a better answer here. Corak is correct. I set property to not copy, deleted copy in bin\debug folder and app wouldn't run in debug mode because it couldn't find db even though paths all point to other file location. App is looking for copy in bin\debug. Ultimately, it was working all along. I recommend someone to make a connection to the copy in bin\debug so they can test values in the Server Explorer. Thanks for your help Corak and everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*If your solution is web application, make sure Database1.sdf location path is under the 
     * App_Data folder 
     * Web.Config <add name="LocalDB" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf"/>
     */
    protected string ConnString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDB"].ToString();
        }
    }

    /*
     * or you can use try absolute path as connectionstring
     * modify your directory path as PhysicalApplicationPath result
     */
    public string BaseDirConnString
    {
        get
        {
            if ((HttpContext.Current == null) || (HttpContext.Current.Request == null))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("...");
            }

            return @"Data Source=" + HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "VIN Decoder\\Database1.sdf";
        }
    }

    protected SqlCeConnection SqlCeConnection
    {
        get
        {
            var connection = new SqlCeConnection(BaseDirConnString);
            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }
    }
```